# bash - Shell script opening multiple terminals and executing distinct commands

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I've tried to write my own shell script. So far I've managed to open 4 xterminals that can only execute ONE command because of the 'hold' option.

If i don't use this option, the terminals just disappear.

Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -title "App 1" -hold -e mycommand | mysecondcommand  &
xterm -title "App 2" -hold -e mycommand | mysecondcommand  &
xterm -title "App 3" -hold -e mycommand | mysecondcommand  &
xterm -title "App 4" -hold -e mycommand | mysecondcommand
```

Not so sure if I'm supposed to execute the second command in the same terminal that way.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: What are the commands you are trying to run? You should be able to execute multiple commands by using `-e "command1; command2; command3 &"` etc. Maybe consider batching these commands into another script and calling that instead?

Comment: first i need to cd to another directory then execute a program

But still, the main problem is the -hold option :/

Comment: What if you try: `xterm -title "App 1" -e "cd /my/dir && mycommand"` ?

Comment: @JoshJolly
When I try without -hold, it appears for half a second and then it's gone

Also I can't CD anywhere : "No Such File" with

    xterm -title "App 1" -e cd /home/

Comment: Does /home/ exist? Are you putting quotes around your command? If you do something like `xterm -title "App 1" -e "touch testfile"`, does the testfile get created?

Comment: OKay, putting quotes helped @JoshJolly

Still if i take off -hold, it disappears..

Comment: So.. the command is executed? That is the behaviour of xterm, if you don't use -hold, then it will close as soon as the command is complete. What do you want to happen?

Comment: It's okay your several answers helped me a lot ! I can now execute multiple commands in multiple terminals. give a final answer with the final code to my question and I'll give you the points. @JoshJolly

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without `-hold`, the xterm will close as soon as the command is completed. You can execute multiple commands by using double quotes and command separators (eg `;`, `&`):

```
xterm -title "App 1" -e "mycommand; mysecondcommand"
```

Comment: How would you do this using `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: @gone You'll have to replace `xterm` by `gnome-terminal` and remove the option (`-title` and `--hold`). Consult the gnome-terminal man page (`man gnome-terminal`) for further options.